# table not showing data when uses pagintion

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a from like this

```
<h:form id="logForm" prependId="false">
    <div class="leftcol">
    ....
    <h:commandButton value="Apply Filters"
        action="#{exporterReview.applyFilterAction}">    
    </h:commandButton><br></br><br></br>
    ....
    </div>

    <div class="rightcol1" >
        <p:dataTable  var="exporter" 
                      value="#{exporterReview.exporters}"
                      paginator="true" rows="5"
                      height="400" paginatorPosition="top"
                      emptyMessage="#{exporterReview.noExporterFound}">

            <p:column>

                <div style="....">
                    <h:graphicImage value="#{exporter.imgPath}" />
                </div>

                <div style="...">
                    <h:commandButton value="Update" 
                                     action="#{exporterReview.updateExporter}"         
                                     rendered="#{login.updateState}"  
                                     style="... ">
                        <f:param name="exporterid" 
                                 value="#{exporter.exporterId}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </div>

                <div class="arrowbuttons">
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </div>
                <p:spacer height="10" width="20"/>
                <h:commandButton  value="#{exporter.organizationName}" 
                                  action="#{exporterReview.viewExporter}" 
                                  style="...">
                    <f:param name="exporterid" value="#{exporter.exporterId}" />
                    <f:param name="disableLink" value="#{exporter.disableLink}" />
                </h:commandButton>

                <div style='padding-top:10px'>
                    <h:outputLabel value="City: "  style="color: #1c6ace;"/>
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not exporter.disableLink}">
                        <h:commandLink value="#{exporter.cityName}" 
                                       style="text-decoration: underline" 
                                       disabled="#{exporter.disableLink}" 
                                       onclick="openCityPopup(#{exporter.cityId});" >
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{exporter.disableLink}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{exporter.cityName}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>

                <div style='padding-top:3px'>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Email Address: " style="color: #1c6ace;"/>
                    <a href="mailto:#{exporter.emailAddress}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{exporter.emailAddress}" 
                                      style="..">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div style='padding-top:3px'>
                    <h:outputText value="#{exporter.categoryDesc}" 
                                  escape="false" />
                </div>

                <div class="horizontalline"></div>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Here is the filter method

```
public void applyFilterAction() {
    ....
    //Setting whereParam so that whenever user navigate from page And return back
    // the grid is populated with the previous search criteria
    session.setAttribute("settingWhereParam", whereParam);
    getExporterGrid();

} //end of applyFilterAction

private void getExporterGrid() {
    ....
    exporters.add(new Exporter(Datatable values));

} //end of getExporterGrid
```

The problem is when i am on first page and do the search then every thing works fine. Here is the first picture.
[image]

Then if i apply search then it becomes

[image]

But if i do pagination , say go to page 4 and then apply the search then no result shows

[image]

But then nothing show

[image]

Why it is happening? What i am doing wrong ? I am using Prime faces 2.2. Its an old program.

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest trying to debug to see if the data actually exists after going to page 4 and then applying the filters.

Comment: yes data is there, i have debug and checked. It seems that somehow table is not refreshing itself to get the values...Is it a bug of prime faces 2.2 ?

Comment: If i try to done programatically, then as soon as i use `binding="#{exporterReview.exporterDataTable}"` and then in the code `exporterDataTable.setPaginator(true);` But then pagination does not appear. If i bind my dataTable , then pagination disappear. i checked with firebug for any js error, but no js error.... i think it is a bug of Prime Faces 2.2....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in primefaces 2.2, but in version 3+, you can specify an update attribute.

Your commandButton would look like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Apply Filters" action="#{exporterReview.applyFilterAction}" update="@form">
```

Comment: are you sure about h:commandButton... i think p:commandButton has an update attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I did it :). Actually i did a workaround. What i did, i used onClick event on my filter Button. Like

```
<h:commandButton id="filterButton"
                 value="Apply Filters"
                 style=""
                 action="#{exporterReview.applyFilterAction}"
                 onclick="filterButtonClick(event)" />
```

Now when button is clicked, then first my client side code will run. So i get all the values and then using ajax call the servlet, and save the result in session object. After that my server side code will run, and my action method invoked, in which i simple return the url of the same page.

```
public String applyFilterAction() {

    return "Exporter_Review?faces-redirect=true";

} //end of applyFilterAction()
```

Now when page invoke i simply check for the result in the session. And if session object present then simply get the values from that object and shows the result. And when i leave the page i simply put null in the session against object, now default is used. Now everything is working fine :)